# FB.login cancel button do a redirect

Tags: facebook-graph-api, fbconnect

currently i have a page under http://mydomain.com/me/myself/1234
on this page i've included a custom share link, to share information on this page to facebook.
imagine that you're not logged into facebook but in my application and you come to the above page. If you click on the link a FB login pop up appears to give you a chance to authenticate. my code for posting to the wall looks like this:

```
function loggedIn() {

    if (typeof(FB) != 'undefined' && FB != null ) {

    FB.login(function(response) {
           if (response.session || response.authResponse) {
            postToWall(); 
           } else {
             return false,              
               }

         }, {scope: 'publish_stream'});
     return false;
    }
}

function postToWall() {
    var prodName= 'test';
    var prodPic = 'test.jpg';
    var linkUrl = 'http://mydomain.com/me/myself/1234';
    var tmpObj = new Object();
    tmpObj.value = "CUSTOM";
    tmpObj.friends = "ALL_FRIENDS";

    var wallPost = {
            message : " I've seen a " + prodName ,
            picture : prodPic,
            link: linkUrl,
            name: "the name",
            description: "a little description",
            privacy: tmpObj

        };
        FB.api('/me/feed', 'post', wallPost , function(response) {

          if (!response || response.error) {
            //alert('Error occured');

          } else {
            //alert('Post ID: ' + response);
          }
        });

    }
```

So, the only issue now is: if i click the cancel button on the login dialog, i get redirected to my .com page http://mydomain.com. what i need is to stay on the same page. I don't see the error i'm doing.

Would appreciate any help.
best regards,
Ramo

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you have a function called **loggedIn()** calling a function called **postToWall()**. You might want to refactor or rename the **loggedIn()** function.

You did not post the event handler code for your button. However, if you are catching the click event but **not returning false** then not only will the facebook login window get shown, but the normal thing that occurs when you click on a link on a web page will also happen. That said, it doesn't sound like that's the problem but please post more code so that we may know for sure.